# Error Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID. WCF with COM

Tags: wcf, com, marshalling, clsid

How can i solve the next problem that i have. Im using WCF and it reference a COM.

```
Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {...} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: fffffdf8f Exception from HRESULT:0XFFFFFDF8F
```

Obviously the CLSID that appears is my COM. My COM is compiled in Power Builder 11.5.

It appears in production environment after a long time of using but at the beginning of the day it work perfectly.

Do you think I should use `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(COM)`?